# GLSL File: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, glsl

I am building image transition with a custom shader and for this i need a fragment.glsl.
But when importing this file into my .js, this error shows up:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/shaders/fragment.glsl 1:13

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> void main () {
| 
| }
```

For a fast start i am using this webpack boilerplate:
https://github.com/taniarascia/webpack-boilerplate

Because of my not existing experience in webpack and glsl files i dont know whats wrong. I am assuming, that the browser is not able to read the file. I tried a lot of stuff with webpack.config.js and modules like glfl-loader but looks like my browser got other plans.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace!

Answer (score 0):

After testing around i found the solution:

i had to edit this to the `webpack.config.js`

// Shader

```
{ test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/,  type: 'asset/source',generator: { filename: 'assets/images/[hash][ext]' }}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).